# Convert a string to correct date format (joomla format)

Tags: php, date

I got a barebone joomla version (so just pure php using the joomla cms and table names). And the published date of an article is saved like this:

```
2016-04-06 14:38:52
```

How can I convert that string into something like:

```
6 April 2016
```

So ignore the time and only use the date in the correct format.

How can this be done using PHP (no joomla build in functions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with  **[date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)** and **[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)** function of php

```
$t="2016-04-06 14:38:52";
echo date('j F Y', strtotime($t));
```

> F :-  A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
>
> j :-  Day of the month without leading zeros
>
> Y :- A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

**OUTPUT**

> 6 April 2016

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also in object oriented way:

```
//create a DateTimeObject
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);

echo $dateTime->format('j F Y'); //output: 6 April 2016
```

Explanation of `j F Y`:

> ```
> j - Day of the month without leading zeros
> F - A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
> Y - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
> ```

Comment: Please add more to your answer you basically copy pasted @Saty's answer

Comment: It's not copy, @Saty has wrong order of letters in first argument of `date` function.

Comment: The problem was that your answer didn't add anything new before your update. The OP could have adjusted the letter order after finding out what they represent

Comment: @SuperDJ, because me and Saty added answers basically in same time. So I've edited my answer and shows this mechanism using `DateTime` object. Is that adding anything new now?

Comment: Your solution is also correct !!

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this using the `DateTime` class native to PHP.

```
$date = "2016-04-05 16:00:00";
$odate = DateTime:createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Note that I use the `createFromFormat` method to initiate the `DateTime` object. This will prevent dates such as `2016-04-05` from being interpreted in the wrong way. This date could just as well be The 4th of May.

Now, to output

```
// Output
echo $oDate->format('j F Y');
```

> F - A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
>
> j - Day of the month without leading zeros
>
> Y - A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits

Comment: Your solution is also correct and alternate of both answer!!